# Is there any difference between different ways of expressing the same information in an SPF record?

Tags: email, spf

I have a domain at `example.com`. The MX record is `10 cp.example.net`. These domains are on two different IP addresses. Let's say that `example.com` is on 198.51.100.0, while `example.net` and `cp.example.net` are on 203.0.113.0. Outgoing mail also goes from `cp.example.net`.

It seems to me that I could indicate this information in SPF records in a few different ways:

Outgoing mail comes from the same place as incoming mail:

```
v=spf1 mx -all
```

Outgoing mail comes from `cp.example.net`:

```
v=spf1 a:cp.example.net -all
```

Outgoing mail comes from 203.0.113.0:

```
v=spf1 ip4:203.0.113.0 -all
```

Is there any difference between these different ways of indicating the same information? Is there any reason to prefer one over the other? (I’m inclined to favour the first because it’s shorter, but if there’s any technical reason to prefer one of the others, I’m all ears.)

Comment: One difference is for the receiver: the first requires two DNS lookups, the second one, the third none.

Comment: I don't know that it justifies an answer, but this question ought to have an accepted answer so it doesn't float around forever like Banquo's ghost.  So OK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another main difference is for the receiver:

- the first requires two additional DNS lookups for him/her to evaluate (one to resolve the MX record to a hostname, the other to resolve that hostname to an address or addresses);
- the second requires one additional lookup (to resolve the hostname to an address or addresses);
- the third requires no additional lookup and can be evaluated by the receiver as it stands.

Comment: Accepting because this, while obvious in retrospect, would probably never have occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

These representations differs at what you will be able to change without modifying SPF:

- If you select just mx you will be able to change IP or MX pointer without modifying SPF.
- In case of a:cp.example.net, your spf will be bound to cp.example.net name.
- And with ip4:203.0.113.0 you will be able to change MX, but not IP without modifying SPF.

MX is quite good, if you mail server is the only one sending email. And add A or IP records, if you need other hosts sending them.